# Is this mould on my bed frames?

Tags: mold, bedroom

There is no spread or other visible marks surrounding the bed, but these white spots are scattered around most of the frame.

Is it mould?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not likely, mold needs the correct conditions to grow, and metal is not generally a porous enough surface to support growth. That looks like an aluminum frame, so I would guess that is oxidation popping through the paint.

If you believe it is still mold I would refer to this [CDC article on mold](https://www.cdc.gov/mold/faqs.htm#:%7E:text=Mold%20will%20grow%20in%20places,carpet%2C%20fabric%2C%20and%20upholstery).

Either way, you can wash it with a mild detergent and water, if it is mold, this should kill it. You can find a lot of references to using bleach for mold, but this if often more hazardous than the mold and should not be used

Answer (score 1):

Mold needs darkness (which you have) and humidity which you should not have.

Those dots are aluminum defects (oxidation) from manufacturing process. You can polish them away with very fine sand paper and apply a coat of transparent lack.

Comment: What is "lack"?

Comment: @isherwood german for transparent paint